# Use cucumber and XRAY in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber in my project with protractor and now I want to integrate it with Jira using XRAY but looking at the documentation, it uses jasmine and I don't know how to use both frameworks because if I put the code as indicated in the documentation using the "jasmine" framework instead of "custom" it doesn't recognize the cucumber sentences of the features.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance
I include package.json and xrayconfig.ts .

xrayconfig.ts:

```
import { Config, protractor } from 'protractor';
import * as reporter from "cucumber-html-reporter";
import 'jasmine';
const XrayReporter = require('protractor-xray-reporter');
let onPrepareDefer;
let onCompleteDefer;
export let config: Config = {
    directConnect: true,//Running chrome
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    "types": ["chai", "cucumber", "node"],
    specs: ['../Features/*.feature'],
    cucumberOpts: {
      tags:"@scenarioLola",  //only executed this scenario
        
        require: [
            '../JSFiles/stepDefinitions/*.js' // accepts a glob
        ]
    },

    'onPrepare': function() {
        let globals = require('protractor');
       let browser = globals.browser;
        onPrepareDefer = protractor.promise.defer();
        onCompleteDefer = protractor.promise.defer();
 
        const options = {
            'screenshot': 'always',
            'version': '1.0',
            'jiraUser': 'user',
            'jiraPassword': 'pwd',
            'xrayUrl': 'https://jira.com/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution'
        };
 
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(XrayReporter(options, onPrepareDefer, onCompleteDefer, browser));
 
        return onPrepareDefer.promise;
    },
    'onComplete': function() {
        return onCompleteDefer.promise;
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project one",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "protractor JSFiles/cucumberconfig.js",
    "pretest": "tsc",
    "protractor": "./node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js",
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "author": "Carol",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.13",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "protractor-zephyr-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Is your solution working? If yes can you please post your solution here, i want to accomplish the same in my Protractor project.